# mod_expires caching directives not fully supported by chrome and safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, mod-expires

we're wanting to use caching directives to tell the browser to fetch resources from the source (our server) only if we've modified the resources. According to Apache, we can use the "modification" base clause as well as "access".

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html

We're finding that all browsers are supporting "access" but Chrome and Safari do not support "modification". We've tried both the following types of syntax :

```
FileETag MTime Size

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html "modification 1 minute"
```

and

```
FileETag MTime Size

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html M60
```

When we use "access" we can see in the Browser's inspectors that the Expires Header is set to 1 minute after the Date Header. However when we use "modification" the Expires Header is an exact match to the Date Header.

```
Date:Thu, 03 Sep 2015 12:31:44 GMT
Expires:Thu, 03 Sep 2015 12:31:44 GMT
```

Anyone know a way of using "modification" which is supported by all major browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because when using "modification" the cached files are honoured by all browsers. So when I was setting the cache to "modification plus 1 minute" and downloading the file in Firefox, it would set the expiry date to the file's last modified time plus 1 minute. For example :

Expires:Thu, 03 Sep 2015 19:49:03 GMT

Now, 1 minute later when I tried to view it in another browser (Safari or Chrome) , because the file had not been modified on the server, those browsers would display and use the Expires Header from the cache record stored by Firefox.

What this means is that, exactly 1 minute after the file is modified on the server, the cached copy will no longer be used by any browser (client) on the user's computer.

Excerpt from [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) :

```
The base time is either the last modification time of the file, or the time of the client's access to the document. Which should be used is specified by the <code> field; M means that the file's last modification time should be used as the base time, and A means the client's access time should be used.
```

Using modification base time is generally a bad idea, as the file will no longer be cached after the lapsed time, until you actually modify it on the server again. You'd generally use the modification base time for files that are updated at regular intervals, rather than random intervals.